# Correct way to unbind an Open GL ES texture?

Tags: ios, c, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I have drawing code that first draws the background without a texure, then overlays the texture on top of it. I'm currently using `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)` in order to un-bind the texture after performing the second lot of drawing.

However, this is generating the following warning when I analyse the GPU performance in Xcode:

[image]

When I remove the code to un-bind the texture, the warning disappears, but things aren't drawn correctly. The texture that I'm drawing doesn't have mipmapping enabled, so it's not coming from there.

**Drawing Code:**

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

{ // Drawing

    glViewport(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);

    GLuint vertexCount = animBuffer.vertexCounts[animIndex];

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, animBuffer.vertexBuffers[animIndex]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, animBuffer.indexBuffers[animIndex]);

    glVertexAttribPointer(positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(colorSlot, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), (GLvoid*)(sizeof(float)*3));
    glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordSlot, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), (GLvoid*)(sizeof(float)*7));

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, vertexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);


    // glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) (tried this, gives another warning)

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glUniform1i(textureUniform, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureColorBuffer); // Transparent color buffer to allow texture to be overlayed.
    glVertexAttribPointer(colorSlot, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)(sizeof(float)*3));

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, vertexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    // Unbind texture.... this line is causing the error.
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    // glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) (tried this, gives another warning)    
}

[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

**Texture Loading Code:**

```
CGImageRef textureImage = image.CGImage;

size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(textureImage);
size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(textureImage);

GLubyte* spriteData = malloc(width*height*4);

CGColorSpaceRef cs = CGImageGetColorSpace(textureImage);
CGContextRef c = CGBitmapContextCreate(spriteData, width, height, 8, width*4, cs, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease(cs);

CGContextScaleCTM(c, 1, -1);
CGContextTranslateCTM(c, 0, -CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(c).size.height);

CGContextDrawImage(c, (CGRect){CGPointZero, {width, height}}, textureImage);
CGContextRelease(c);

GLuint glTex;
glGenTextures(1, &glTex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTex);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);


glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, (GLsizei)width, (GLsizei)height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, spriteData);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

free(spriteData);

return glTex;
```

How should I go about un-binding textures in order to remove this warning?

**EDIT:**

I have tried using `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` & `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` before and after the textured drawing, although this now gives me the following warning:

[image]

Comment: This warning might go away if you explicitely set `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LOD`  of every non-mipmapped texture to 0 via `glTexParameter`.

Comment: Can't find that parameter `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LOD`... was it deprecated in ES 2.0?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LOD` is not available in ES.

Comment: I don't think 0 is for unbinding a texture. A 0 is actually a valid texture if I remember correctly. Also I do not remember anything like "unbinding a texture". You may disable the texture by using glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D). I still see no reason for disabling or unbinding the texture in versions higher then 1.x. What is the reason you are trying to this?

Comment: Could you post a texture initialisation code?

Comment: I've added the texture loading code to the OP. I don't think that's the source of the problem as the texture doesn't use mipmapping, I think it's something to do with the texture 0 that Matic is talking about... Let me try using `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` and get back to you. I need to unbind the texture in order to first draw the background of the scene without texture, and then overlay the texture over using OpenGL alpha blending. As far as I'm aware, there isn't another way of doing this.

Comment: I tried using `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` & `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` before and after the textured drawing, results in another warning that I have added to the OP.

Comment: `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` is not valid in ES 2.0. That was only used in the legacy fixed pipeline of desktop OpenGL. I suspect that the warning is just a problem in the tool, and has nothing to do with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to avoid this warning is to keep the texture binded, but just send a `uniform` to the fragment shader indicating whether to blend the texture or not.

So, before drawing just add:

```
glUniform1i(drawTexInput, GL_FALSE); // Or GL_TRUE to draw.
```

And in the fragment shader:

```
varying lowp vec4 destinationColor;

uniform bool drawTex;
varying lowp vec2 texCoordOut;
uniform sampler2D tex;

void main() {

    lowp vec4 result;
    if (drawTex) {
        lowp vec4 tex2D = texture2D(tex, texCoordOut);
        result = tex2D + vec4(1.0 - tex2D.a) * destinationColor; // Alpha blending
    } else {
        result = destinationColor;
    }

    gl_FragColor = result;
}
```